# What are the best practices for automating test cases in a dynamic web application with frequently changing UI elements?

Tags: web-application, web

I'm currently working on automating test cases for a dynamic web application, and I'm facing a challenge due to the frequent changes in UI elements. The application's UI components often undergo updates, making it challenging to maintain and execute automated tests consistently.

I'd like to seek your advice and insights on how to effectively handle this situation. Specifically, I'm interested in best practices, strategies, and tools that you've found helpful in dealing with dynamic web applications. Here are a few points I'd like to discuss:

- Element Locators: What strategies do you use to create robust element locators that can withstand UI changes?
- Page Object Model: How do you structure your Page Object Model (POM) to accommodate dynamic elements and changes in the UI?
- Test Data Management: Any tips for managing test data, especially when the application's UI changes may impact the data input or output?
- Continuous Integration: How do you integrate automated tests into your CI/CD pipeline to ensure they adapt to UI changes and provide quick feedback?
- Tools and Frameworks: Are there specific tools or automation frameworks that excel in handling dynamic UI changes?
- Monitoring and Alerts: Do you employ any monitoring or alerting mechanisms to detect UI changes proactively?

Comment: Welcome to SQA Stack Exchange. You'll probably get better results if you split each of your points into a separate question. This will allow you to get answers specific to each point.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I think it would help if you better clarify what you mean by "dynamic." Most, if not all, web apps these days are dynamic, meaning they use Async processes, event/message queues, user-supplied data (social media, comments), content changes (blogs), etc. How are you using "dynamic" differently or is it the same as "frequent UI elements changes?"

Comment: Also, ideally, you don't want to test content since it changes all the time. You want to focus more on the usability of the software regardless of content.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious answer is do not go for UI test with locator (That are flaky anyways) that is just the answer if your UI changes quite often. But some solutions can be:

- Use relative Xpath (Usually, something like text()/ id or some if you are not using already )
- You can switch to API test altogether if your UI changes quite often
- If you still want to give it a shot you can use things like helenium [It works somewhat
- Use visual regression testing

These tools might be useful :

- https://applitools.com/platform/eyes/
- https://healenium.io/
- https://testsigma.com/